# Rendering two arrays linked by ID's with two-way data binding

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

I built this rudimentary tool for creating a **Menu** where multiple/identical **Source items** may be attached (1 to many).
This isn't really a merge, because I need **Source items** to be editable and data bound to all it's instances in the **Menu**.
This involves two arrays: one the **Source** and the other for **Menu** where a common ID connects the items and ID's for their sub-items. Menu includes inputs for override/customization.

The problem I am having is with refreshing the data when changes are made.  I've had to resort to using `$.templates("#myTmpl").link("#renderMenu", data)` into two different places as data is changed.
This is not ideal as it re-renders everything; although in my case everything in two-way data bound, so no loss.
`view.refresh()` does not work either

I think the problem is because `itemVar` does not get updated when it's underlying data is changed...`itemVar` is for single pass rendering from what I understand.
I also tried helpers in place of `itemVar` like `^~items=myItems`...they didn't work either.

So the question is how to trigger refreshing on certain view's/parts without resorting to: `<$.templates("#myTmpl").link("#renderMenu", data)>`

To test:

1. Comment out line 152 `$.templates("#menuTmpl").link("#renderMenu", data)`
2. Run
3. Press **Insert new item** and pick any item from select list.
4. Problem is here...it doesn't render the matching item detail from the **Source item**.  I believe it all starts with `itemVar="~currentItem"` on line 8, where itemVar does not get updated nor trigger a refresh.  The underlying data is changed however.

Perhaps there is a better way of building this tool or parts of it; as it includes a bit of trickery (`filter ... step=100`) and probably unnecessary 'for' looping.
I'll admit...it took me 5 versions to build as it was very tricky getting all things working together.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Fiddle showing the problems: https://jsfiddle.net/alnico/mt5d2v7j/ 
There are ID's on all rendered items for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about `itemVar` not updating - in the sense that if a new array item is added, the view for that item does not have an `itemVar` contextual parameter (such as `~currentItem` in your sample). I will fix that in the next update. I created an issue here https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/424, and you can test it out with the updated jsviews.js file you will find there.

The other immediate issue you have is that you have:

```
{^{for ~root[1].allItems filter=~menuItem id=id}}
```

But the `menuItem` filter depends on the `id`, so it needs to be refreshed whenever `id` changes. You can achieve that either by declaring the dependency on the  menuItem function:

```
$.views.helpers.menuItem.depends = "id";
```

or by using [mapDepends](https://www.jsviews.com/#tagoptions@mapprops):

```
{^{for ~root[1].allItems filter=~menuItem id=id mapDepends='id'}}
```

You can simplify things a bit by removing the `id=id` and writing

```
menuItem: function(item, index, items) {
  return item.id == this.view.data.id;
}
```

Or better, don't use a filter on the `{{for}}`, but simply use a helper function to return the filtered items directly:

```
getItem: function(id) {
  return data[1].allItems.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id == id;
  });
}
```

used like this:

```
{^{:#index}}
{^{for ~getItem(id)}}
  {^{if ~currentItem.isNewItem != '1'}}
```

If you do that you no longer need to use mapDepends or .depends on your filter function. Changes in `id` will trigger a refresh of `{^{for ~getItem(id)}}`

Comment: Thanks Boris for the speedy fix and mapDepends scenarios, much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to maintain your observable selectedItems array alongside your allItems - so if you remove an item from allItems, you need also to observable remove from selectedItems any items that correspond to that id. Not sure about what the feature you are enquiring about would be or how it would work. AFAIK it does not correspond to an existing feature. Docs on jsviews.com are pretty complete, so you can search there whether anything corresponds.